# Are computers bad for health?

Tags: sleep, eye, computers, lifestyle

I am a CS student, so my career requires sitting for long periods of time (8~9) hours infront of a laptop daily. I've been hearing for quite a long time that computers are harmful for health. I'm really concerned with my health but I'm  comfortable with this lifestyle.

Is there any proof that computers are harmful and/or they cause serious health problems ? Are there any health problems that are specific to some types of computers that no more exist with modern hardware ?

#### Clarification

I'm interested in physical and cognitive/brain problems alike.
Cognitive problems are more important in this case.

Examples of physical problems likely for long-time computer users:

- Back bending.
- Eye-sight damage.
- Less energy consumption problems (because of sitting all day) like sleeping problems.

Examples of cognitive problems likely for long-term for computer users:

- Loss of attention.
- [Cognitive effects of learning computer programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.359.8341&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: I don't have an answer but can share my personal experience. I'm also a CS researcher and I had dry eyes which caused a burning sensation in eyes. I think dry eyes can be with any computer type. It was mainly due to reduced blinking rate. Doctor advised me to take regular breaks, blink at a normal rate and look out of my window to the farthest object I can see. Also, he said that air conditioner promotes drying so advised to keep a bowl of water near my PC. I had to use artificial tears for some time but now the problem is gone. I'm also looking for a good answer to your question.

Comment: @Ruchir - Please avoid pseudo answers in comments. Comments are intended for refining and clarifying questions or answers. Thank you! :)

Comment: http://annals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2091327

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you specified what you heard. To list every possible health risk and give evidence that would either prove or refute it, would make quite a long answer. Also, just to search for such evidence (if you wanted a list of only "confirmed" health risks) would make a very long and extensive search. Is there a particular health risk (group of risks) that you are interested in?

Comment: @JohnP thanks for the guideline. I'll avoid such kind of comments in the future :)

Comment: @Lucky: I mean the _usual_ set of risks the comes with using a computer for prolonged periods, like back bending (which's solution is using a laptop), or eye damage. Things following that model: A risk, its possible solution if it exists and a note.

Comment: You can edit your question to include that you are primarily interested in eye and back problems. The question [How can I protect my eyesight when using computers?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-protect-my-eyesight-when-using-computers) probably offers a partial answer to your question.

Comment: To protect your eyesight you can practice the Bates Method - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like all things too much of anything is bad for you. As a designer working in the tech industry for over a decade, here's a few things I experienced and that might (I hope not) impact you.

- wrists from over use of keyboard and mouse
- circulation problems from being seated for too long
- eye sight
- posture problems
- social effects of not going out and socializing but using social media to socialize (which isnt really socializing)

Sources:

1. (study on carpal tunnel syndrome- wrists)
   http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=196717
2. (computer vision syndrome)
   http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/computer-vision-syndrome
3. (American Optometric Association)
   http://www.aoa.org/Documents/optometrists/effects-of-computer-use.pdf
4. (sitting & posture)
   https://www.washingtonpost.com/apps/g/page/national/the-health-hazards-of-sitting/750/
5. (social interaction) https://www.elon.edu/docs/e-web/academics/communications/research/vol6no1/02DragoEJSpring15.pdf

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this is not the average SE site. Here, [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) are required, even if the answer has some correct information; otherwise it's opinion, not based on *evidence*. The [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help section](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) will provide more information about the site, as will a quick look at the top voted answers and at meta. Again, welcome.

Comment: @anongoodnurse glad to hear we require sources now! Took a hiatus, but I'm back and excited to contribute.

Comment: @DaveL - it's always a pleasure to remove a post notice. Thanks for your contributions!